# How to get dataItem from kendoTreeInstance.dataSource.get when loadOnDemand is set to true

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

In Kendo TreeView I am trying to get an element of a node, 
To get node element I trying below code:

```
var dataItem = kendoTreeInstance.dataSource.get("2");
var dataElement = kendoTreeInstance.findByUid(dataItem.uid);
```

Since `loadOnDemand` is set to *true*, I am not getting the dataItem of child nodes. Is there any work around to get the dataItem of a child node when loadOnDemand is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

When using a `TreeView`, the underlying datasource is a [`HierarchicalDataSource`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/hierarchicaldatasource), that handles instances of the [`Node`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/node) type.

If `loadOnDemand` is true, you need to call the [`load()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/node/methods/load) method of your dataItem (which is in fact a `Node`) before you can access its children.

Note that calling the `load()` method will trigger the `change` event of your datasource.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I was able to solve this by expanding parent nodes in the kendo tree hierarchy till the child node using [expandPath](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview/methods/expandpath). Then I was able to get the data Item and data Element of the child node.